# Overfitting training data but still improving on test data

Tags: neural-network, spacy, bert-language-model

My machine learning model massively overfits the training data but still performs quite well on test data. When using a neural network approach every iteration increases the accuracy on the test set slightly but increases the accuracy on the train set much more (overfit).

The problem is nicely demonstrated when using spacy with a CNN architecture in which I am getting the following results

```
ITER    LOSS      P       R       F      TF  
 0      29.305  0.733   0.342   0.466   0.525
 1      10.410  0.811   0.443   0.573   0.650
 2      4.361   0.722   0.548   0.623   0.757
 3      2.265   0.764   0.563   0.648   0.811
 4      1.449   0.748   0.613   0.674   0.877
```

TF is the f1 score on the train data.

The test score keeps improving while the divergence from the train set just increases to the point where in the 20th iteration the model performs almost perfectly on the train data while the test accuracy never decreasing to justify early stopping.

I have tried number a number of regularisation options, including varying dropout, weight decay, L2 but none seems to avoid memorizing parts of the training data and all perform worse on the test set.

The problem is not unique to spacy and to the approach I followed, it also happens with scikit and models with fewer parameters.

The dataset in hand is a small dataset of less than 2000 examples which is a multi-label text classification task. Some labels have fewer than 100 examples but when inspecting where overfit happens all labels seem to be affected equally.

I guess my main question is whether I should worry about the fact that the model is memorizing the training dataset as long as it performs well on the test data but also whether there are other things I have not considered in order to address this memorisation problem as I see it.

Comment: A plot of `train_acc` vs `test_acc` and `train_loss` vs `test_loss` would be useful. Anyway I don't think it's a bad overfitting problem if `test_loss` and `test_acc` keep improving.

Comment: Just to clarify, what you are describing here is certainly **not** overfitting.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Also, how would you call it?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, your loss function is always calculated on Training set, and thus overfitting may happen on the training set. To observe if there is overfitting, kindly use a DEV set (Which shouldn't be part of training set.). At the end of every epoch, calculate the loss on training-set and dev-set separately. Reducing loss function on dev-set shows well fitting of the model. While, increasing loss reveals overfitting. (You can use early stopping at this point, with some patience. But can always use a checkpoint to save the weights of performing their best). And the number epochs required to converge depends on the Learning rate, so a very lower learning rate may require lots of epoch for the model to fit.

Comment: Do you reckon that the results of observing accuracy on train vs dev will be different from comparing the loss function on dev/train. What I mean is that I do have a dev set in which I am calculating f1 and observe overfitting in the sense that my f1 score in the train set is much higher than the dev set.

Comment: F1 score in train set get get higher than dev set, that's the objective of loss function.

Comment: In cases where you have generalised well you would expect these scores to be the same but I understand your point that to a certain degree it is expected to improve slighly better for train since this is what the loss function is optimising.

Comment: Yes, you would expect it to be the same, that's the reason you would use early stopping at a point when validation loss starts to increase.